# Apollo GraphQL and React equivalent to redux-logger

Tags: logging, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am learning `graphql` and wanted to know if logging solutions exist for the `apollo-client`.

I find `redux-logger` to be a tremendous tool to debug an React/Redux app and wanted to know if something of the sort exists for `appolo-client` ?

I would like to see the state of my `store` at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess I should have researched a bit more.

It is well explained here: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/redux.html#creating-a-store

In case it interests anyone, this is how I implemented `apollo-client` with `redux-logger`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import  ApolloCient from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import reducers from './reducers';

import App from './App';

// Instantiate Apollo Client
const client = new ApolloCient();

// declare the redux-logger
const logger = createLogger({
  collapsed: true,
  diff: true,
});

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    apollo: client.reducer(), // apollo reducer
    reducers, // your others reducers
  }),
  {},
  compose(
    // apply client.middleware() from ApolloClient and logger from redux-logger
    applyMiddleware(client.middleware(), thunk, promise, logger),

    // If you are using the devToolsExtension, you can add it here also
    // window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
  )
);


const Root = () => {
  return (
    // pass redux store and apollo client to ApolloProvider
    <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root />,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```